# Python built in max() function shadowed by variable of same name appearing later in the program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got a python error that surprised me this morning. Consider this simple example:

```
def f(mylist):
    m = max(mylist)
    max = m
```

I expected this function to execute without failing, but it throws:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'max' referenced before assignment`

I assumed that since python was an interpreted language, overwriting the built-in `max()` function wouldn't cause any trouble as long as I didn't try to invoke it again afterwards.

Why does this behavior occur? Does the python interpreter "look ahead" for variable declarations?

Comment: Use `max1` instead of `max` as `max1 = m`.

Comment: For a more detailed look at Python scoping rules, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules).